# Can somebody help me to debug my nodejs application in IIS express webmatrix through IISnode?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I am using nodejs on my windows. I am able to run my code in webmatrix. Now  I have problem to debug it.

first problem is I can run the application by cmd by going to --debug app.js but PORT 5858 not worked. I thing my firewall have blocked access to it but it's not worked after disable firewall.

I have read http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2011/10/13/using-node-inspector-to-debug-node-js-applications-including-on-windows-and-using-ryppi-for-modules/ .I have found in my installation their is no paperboy file so I can made change.

I have try to run same code from  http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/11/debug-nodejs-applications-on-windows.html and https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode . I can run the same code and debug It by suffix in browser by going to /debug. it's not work on my code who have routing like /login then /login/debug not worked.

Tom on their blog tell one year ago that it's not supported express. Do someone have experienced on debug code on windows. My fellow guys are using Linux or mac and able to run it in better way. Can someone help me to get run my code in windows.

Thanks. Please help me if you have any idea to make it work on my windows.

Comment: I got error 0 when I run node-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your URL rewriting rules are set up such that they do not modify request URLs that target the debugger. A good boilerplate web.config to that effect is at http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/05/yaml-configuration-support-in-iisnode.html. You may need to modify it if the entry point to your application is called something other than server.js.

Then, make sure you are accessing the debugger with the correct URL. If the entry point to your application can normally be accessed at `http://localhost:12345/server.js`, then the debugger can be accessed at `http://localhost:12345/server.js/debug` (as opposed to `http://localhost:12345/debug`).

Comment: Thanks you very much to come here to answer my question. I have tried it from a long time.Finally got it worked.

Comment: Now I have a different problem that If I make some changes in code and refresh browser it's take a long time. If I will close the IIS express and run from webmatrix or vs12 it's not run the IIS.